# float left without efficiency of browser size

Tags: css, scroll, width

I made a image thumb like this,

```
<div id="image_thumb">
    <img src="img1.jpg" />
    <img src="img2.jpg" />
    <img src="img3.jpg" />
    <img src="img4.jpg" />
    <img src="img5.jpg" />
</div>
```

Style

```
#image_thumb { width:100%; max-height:650px; overflow-x:scroll }
img { float:left; max-height:650px; }
```

I wanna make images float left continuously, and show bottom scroll on #image_thumb.
but, Images are floated in browser size. :(

What will I do?

Answer (score 0):

try

```
img { float:left; max-height:650px; display:inline-block;}
```

Answer (score 0):

Give `<div id="image_thumb">` a fixed width instead of `100%`. For example:

```
#image_thumb { width:1000px; max-height:650px; overflow-x:scroll }
```

Comment: Thank you for your solution, but I want get div flexible width!

Answer (score 0):

Give this a try, it should work:

```
<div id="image_thumb">
    <img src="img1.jpg" />
    <img src="img2.jpg" />
    <img src="img3.jpg" />
    <img src="img4.jpg" />
    <img src="img5.jpg" />
</div>

#image_thumb { 
width:80%;
max-height:650px;
margin-left:10%;
margin-right:10%;
overflow-x:scroll
display:inline-block;
}
img {
float:left;
max-height:650px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

When you use `float`, the elements will not overflow its container.

Try:

```
img { display:inline-block; max-height:650px; }
```

Or just:

```
img { max-height:650px; }
```

Answer (score 0):

All you need you do is to stop floating the images, add `white-space:nowrap;` to the thumb so that the row of images can't be broken on spaces, and `word-spacing:-0.25em;` to hide the spaces between the images. Leaving the CSS as:

```
#image_thumb { 
    width:100%; 
    max-height:650px; 
    overflow-x:scroll; 

    white-space:nowrap;
    word-spacing:-0.25em;
}
```

See http://jsfiddle.net/wB7q4/